# How to reference a specific cell on another sheet, but the name of the sheet is in an adjacent cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have multiple sheets named with initials (ABC, DEF, GHI...) and I need to reference the same cell from each sheet in a table. Currently I do this by using `=ABC!B1`, but need to change the sheet name each time. Is there a way to make a single formula that will reference the sheet when it's named in an adjacent cell?

Something like `=(A1)!B1` where cell A1 is the name of a sheet, ABC? Only something Excel can understand.

So, this is what is currently used:

[image: What is currently used]

And this is what I'd like to do:

[image: What I'd like to do]

Sorry If I've not quite explained this right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer to a cell on another sheet you have to explicitly provide the full cell location, such as:

```
=ABC!B1
```

If you want to do this dynamically, you have to use the `Indirect()` function and provide the entire cell location name.  Using your naming convention this formula will return cell B1 from the sheet name stored in cell A1 of your current worksheet.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!"&"B1")
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading up a little on how =INDIRECT works, I've gotten all the referencing done in the workbook in a few minuets, rather than hours.